# Sizer package error when used in global const functions

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-packages

I am using sizer package, for font responsiveness, and I have made custom widget card and global constants , but when I try to add `fontSize : 15.0.sp` in `TextStyle` it shows error that `Const variables must be initialized with a constant value. Try changing the initializer to be a constant expression.`

Here is my main.dart -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Sizer(
      builder: (context, orientation, deviceType) {
        return MaterialApp(....);
```

And this is my constant LabelStyle Function -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'card_widget.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';

const labelStyle = TextStyle(
  fontSize: 15.0.sp,
  color: Color(0xFF8D8E98),
);
```

Is there any way to use this in constant function ? or do I need to remove constants and repeat the code everywhere?

Also is there any way to Change font size for different devices using `responsive_framework package` ?

Any Help Will Be Much Appreciated :)

Comment: FYI, `labelStyle` is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can just choose to not make `labelStyle` `const` and to use `final labelStyle = TextStyle(...);` instead.

Since `labelStyle` is a global variable, it will be initialized only once anyway, so using `const` provides no benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Change `const` to `final`.

with fontsize = 15.0.sp, you're saying Flutter to dynamically change the fontSize and at the same time you're using `const` for that, hence the error.